# What should I attack | tackle next

Tags: word-choice

When talking about a new assignment at work, the scrum master always says

> You should **tackle** ticket [ticketNumber] next.

Is **tackle** the right choice? Can I use **attack** instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those are vernacular, metaphorical terms used in that situation. You can say ***attack*** if you want. However, beware the possibility that there's some sort of organisational culture that expects certain words to be used.

By the by, the rest of the word order isn't quite natural. A ticket number specifies the ticket specifically, so you don't need the definite article. Remove *the* and you have a valid sentence, but it's not natural. The natural word order would be:

> You should tackle ticket [ticketnumber] next.

Or:

> Next you should tackle ticket [ticketnumber].

Comment: is it correct to use *next* between *tackle* and *the ticket*? or should it be *You should tackle the ticket **next*** or *You should tackle the **next** ticket*?

Comment: I don't get the "metaphorical" aspect of using "tackle" in this context.

Comment: @RubioRic: "tackle" can refer to a physical object - as in *fishing tackle* or *block and tackle* -  or for a physical action. The physical action is related to sport, where you attempt to take the ball from someone (as in association football, rugby football or American football), or sometimes just to knock them to the ground (which is also what you do in rugby football and American football). The use in this context is a metaphor for the sporting use of *tackle*.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: the ticket number changes it, though what's in the question is still not quite right. I'll edit to clarify that bit as well, even though it's not what's being asked about...

Comment: @SamBC "by the by"? is it a fancier form of "by the way"?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: more a British alternative than a fancier one, I think. We certainly use both.

Comment: And note that "scrum" itself is a term borrowed from rugby, so it's kind of fitting to borrow another word ("tackle") from the same sport.

Comment: @SamBC the dictionary says that "by the by" translates as "incidentally", but you used it with the meaning of "by the way", didn't you?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko And what does the dictionary say "by the way" means?

Comment: @SamBC sorry, man. I thought it was "accidentally" which wouldn't fit your paragraph. "incidentally" is a new word for me

Answer (score 0):

*Tackling a ticket* means *dealing with that ticket*.

*Attacking a problem/task/ticket/assignment* means *tackling them quickly and in an effective way*.

I suppose *attack* is more informal ([and more aggressive](https://qr.ae/TW7OkS)) than *tackle*.